# QtCreator 2.7.2 (Windows) Console Application: How to paste into console?

Tags: c++, console, console-application, qt-creator, paste

I am using QtCreator 2.7.2 with Windows 8  to develop a C++ Console Application.
I need to use standard input.

When I run the application, an empty console window appears. If I type text then my application processes that text correctly. However, I don't manage to copy and paste text (instead of typing) into the console (Ctrl+V yields '^V', Shift+Insert doesn't work either).

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Right click in console window and select Paste. 
To copy, right-click on console window and select, after Ctrl+C.

Comment: In my console, right clicking doesn't seem work, it doesn't appear any context menu.

However, I discovered that you can left click on the top-left icon,select "Properties", and then check "Enable Quick Edit Mode". After that, you just need to right click in the console to paste the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`shift+print screen`  this equals `ctrl+c`

and

`shift+insert` equals `ctrl+v`